# insert into SQL Server 2008 with csv and get error object or column name is missing or empty

Tags: sql-server, csv

I am trying to load a csv from a mapped network drive.  I can successfully load the data using the import wizard from the mapped drive, however when I try to load the data with a bulk insert I get the following error.

```
Msg 1038, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, 
verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias
names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to 
a valid name.
```

I have truncated the data in the table, which was loaded by the import wizard, so that I can be confident that my data types are the same.

my data looks like the following mapped to a network drive Z and there are no spaces after the last record.

```
col
a
```

I have tried to use this code (masking the ip address of course)  I have obtained the IP Address from the data captured from the import wizard

```
BULK INSERT dbo.test_a
FROM ''\\000.000.95.53\mysql\Z\a.txt''
WITH ( 
    FIELDTERMINATOR ='|', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIRSTROW = 2
  )
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the data being imported to make sure there are no empty or extra cells? I usually do this by opening it in excel and, assuming it is a single column, split the column into multiple columns delimited with the field terminator. I then go to the last column and ctrl + down to make sure it goes to the end of the data set. I then go one right and ctrl + up to make sure it goes to the top and there are no extra cells in this column that should be empty.

Comment: excellent suggestion.  However that was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.  I was using the IP or path address of the local machine and needed to use the IP or path of SQL Server.  In my case I had to remote connect to the SQL Server IP and copy the file from my local drive to the SQL Server drive.